# Don't overcome to call function inside another one

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm working with `django 1.11` and I would like to call a little function inside another one.
The issue comes from parameter inside the called function.

The function lets to get the email from the logged user :

```
def get_user_email(request):
    user_email = request.user.email
    return user_email
```

And the other one make some things, but I need to pick up the email :

```
@shared_task(bind=True, time_limit=3600, soft_time_limit=3600)
def get_xls_export(self, model="", search_info="", query_params=None, **kwargs):
    # Some things
    # Call the previous function
    user_email = get_user_email()
```

Which attributes I have to write in my function in order to call it correctly ?

Thank you

Comment: You don't seem to be passing the `request` argument into your `get_user_email`

Comment: If I write : `get_user_email(request)` it gives me : `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: In the `get_xls_export` task, how do you know which user to fetch the email for?

Comment: @dirkgroten That's the question. Maybe I need to add `user email` argument in `get_xls_export` ?

Comment: that's not a question we can answer based on what you're telling us. I have no idea what `get_xls_export` is doing, where it's being called, how it relates to a specific user and whether it's in the `request` chain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't do this.

Longer answer: in the (totally useless FWIW) `get_user_email()` function, `request` is supposed to be the current `HTTPRequest` instance, which is of course only available within a view. To use it in a celery task, you'd need to pass the `request` object from the view to the task, but that would be a bad idea too (it would couple your task code to a whole lot of things it doesn't need and has no business knowing about, it would make testing much more difficult, and it might even expose sensitive data), if that's even possible actually (not sure how django's `HTTPRequest` supports serialization).

The proper solution here is to force the caller to explicitely pass the informations the task needs, and only those informations. In your case, depending on what you use the user's email for and whether it's ok to have potentially stale data, you want to pass either the plain email, or pass the user's `id` and re-read the model from the task (this makes sure the email is up to date when the task is executed).

And really, this `get_user_email` function (if what you posted is the full implementation of course) is useless and does more harm than good  wrt/ readability.

Comment: Thank you for your very precise answer ! I defined `kwargs` in my view which call the Celery task with `.delay()`. Then I added a `kwargs.pop` to pick up the user's email and it works !

Comment: Note that if that's a required argument, you should add it explicitely to the task function's arguments - `**kwargs` is mainly for _optional_ named args.

Comment: If I understand, I should pass argument through `*args` and not `**kwargs` ?

Comment: No. First, my advice is only valid if it's supposed to be a required argument. And "adding it explicitely" means adding it to the function's arguments, ie `def get_xls_export(self, user_email, model="", search_info="", query_params=None, **kwargs)`.